# How to change Android App Name and ID of an existing application?

Tags: android, android-identifiers

I have two Android projects in Eclipse. I copied the one project from the other, then **changed the app name** (in strings.xml) and **the project name** (in Eclipse).

But now there is a problem: When **I run either of the applications** in the emulator, **the other one gets lost (maybe overwritten?)**. So I guess that there is another setting I have to make, so that Android recognizes the two apps to be different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Package name (in java).

The app name is also in the manifest, although I don't think that needs to be unique, but still would be good to change it for clarity.

Comment: True, changing the package name in Android Manifest helped me.

Comment: How will this affect already downloaded applications if you change everything and "re-release"

Answer (score 17):

Actually you need to change the name in several places:

First, as you said, the name of the string, which is the visible name of the application.

Second, go to activity->src and right click on the package (com.example.whatever) and do refactor->rename;

Then go to the manifest.xml: and change the field in:

```
<manifest package="com.example.whatever" >
```

If you are using native code, JNI, you will also have to change the names of the c++ functions, which is a pain in the ass:

```
Java_com_example_whatever_activity_function()
```

Comment: is there any solution to auto change JNI c++ function package name

Answer (score 17):

For those who aren't using Android Studio and want to do it manually (e.g. if you're using React Native), I just recently went through this and had to change it in the following files:

```
index.android.js
android/settings.gradle
android/app/build.gradle
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
android/app/src/main/java/com/<app id>/MainActivity.java
android/app/src/main/java/com/<app id>/MainApplication.java
```

Answer (score 10):

For Android Studio users, you need to change your package name in AndroidManifest.xml and also in build.gradle file --> defaultConfig--> applicationId.

Answer (score 10):

My setup

- Android Studio 3.5.3
- Kotlin 1.3.x
- macOS 10.14.6

### Solution to Renaming appid

- In Project Explorer, find `app/java/com.company.app`.
- Right-click > `Refactor > Rename`, then select `Rename Package`.
- Look down in the Refactoring Preview and make sure all package references are selected.
- Click `Do Refactor`.

No need to hack around by hand.

Comment: This worked, just had to clean build!

Answer (score 9):

The most simple way I have found to accomplish this task is to utilize Product Flavor in .gradle

```
productFlavors {
    MainApp {
        applicationId = "com.company.app"
    }
    NewAppFlavor {
        applicationId = "com.company.newapp"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" +  getDateAsMillis() + "L)"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

You then specify package name in AndroidManifest.xml as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.company"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="0.1.1" >
```

Upon release configuration, Android Studio (1.5.1 as of this writing) will ask which flavor to build.

Debug configuration is a little less intuitive, you must hover the cursor over the bottom left corner of the screen, select "Build Variants" and select which flavor your debug configuration will deploy when you press the play button.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Android studio then
Your project identifier is in  your `build.gradle` file just change the field `applicationId "com.example.whatEver"`
Hope it will work

Answer (score 3):

I found that my rename wasn't working because I also needed to change the package name in google-services.json

Comment: Can you reuse the same google-services.json without creating a new app in Firebase?

Comment: I don't think so, google-services.json is specific to each application id.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `applicationId` on app gradle.
2. Change file_provider_authority in `strings.xml`
3. If you are using firebase then add new project on firebase and download the new google-services.json file and replace the old one with this.

Optionally change your app name as well.

Comment: Can you reuse the same google-services.json without creating a new app in Firebase? Just changing `client[0].package_name`

Answer (score 1):

An application's unique identifier is the package name.
If you change the package name and reinstall the app again, you will end up with two copies on your phone.

Eclipse can change it on all the places of your code automatically.

Just right click your project on the package explorer (project tree)
and go to Android Tools->Rename Application Package

Voilà.

Answer (score 1):

Select Android on the top left of the Project window. So, right click over your package name under Java folder and select "Refactor" -> Rename...
Click in Rename Package Button. Type the name of the new package you want, mark all options then confirm.

When it shows the results, click on "Do Refactor".

Comment: Thanks, but it only allows renaming the last portion of the package name: instead of `com.example.app` it renames to `com.example.new_app`.

Comment: @SoftDesigner You need to click the cogwheel and remove the selection on "Compact Middle Packages". Now you can change all levels.

Answer (score 0):

After refactoring, a simple "Find and Replace" would help in fixing the renaming in files that were not affected by refactoring

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle select applicationId and press command + shift + r and replace with new package name.
then sync build.gradle.
if you have error in manifest, add package name to start of class