# What do I have to do to change the ApplicationId of an Android App that's already published to the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I don't like the ApplicationId that I used when I first published my App in the play store and want to change it. Is that possible?

I have found [How to change Android App Name and ID of an existing application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563902/how-to-change-android-app-name-and-id-of-an-existing-application) but it only deals with App's within Eclipse and not which Apps that are already published.

Comment: You cannot change app id once it has been published

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the standpoint of Android and the Play Store, an application ID is a unique identifier. You are welcome to modify your project to have a different value for the application ID (e.g., [`applicationId` in `build.gradle`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)). However, that is now a completely different app, from the standpoint of Android and the Play Store.

So, unless you are willing to abandon all of your existing users, I suggest that you leave the application ID alone.