# Dependency screws up app build for Android in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

### TL;DR

After adding [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) to my `pubspec` I cannot startup my application in Android anymore. On start I get the following output in Logcat: `Didn't find class "$prefix.$projectname.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/...`, where `$prefix.$projectname` is not the correct package because I changed it to `$prefix.$name`, where `name` is some other string.

My application starts fine once I remove `url_launcher` again.

---

### Comprehensive

When *only adding* [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) to my `pubspec.yaml` file my application becomes unable to start on **Android**. I do not even have to use any of it in my code.

After some further investigation I found a log message in *Logcat* for Android: `Didn't find class "$prefix.$projectname.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/...`. And this is the origin of the error!

*I changed* my package name **after** creating the project because Flutter is still buggy :) In the creation wizard I typed `$prefix.$name` (*these are just variables; `prefix` is always the same and the other two as well; for reference look at the error message, where I inserted it as well*. On my first build the package name turned out to be `$packagename.$projectname` then. I found a workaround for that: Changing the code directory name in the Android `src` directory and changing `applicationId` name in `build.gradle`.

So now my package name is `$prefix.$name`. My **Android Studio** project name/folder is still `projectname` though. Without `url_launcher` in my `pubspec` everything works fine, but when adding it a directory gets created like this:

*Without `url_launcher`:*

```
project/build/app:
    -generated
    -intermediates
    -outputs
    -tmp
```

*After adding `url_launcher` another directory (besides `app`) suddenly appears in the `build` directory:*

```
project/build/app:
    -generated
    -intermediates
    -outputs
    -tmp
project/build/url_launcher:
    -generated
    -intermediates
    -outputs
    -tmp
```

The `url_launcher` directory in the `build` directory has the same sub-directories as the `app` directory. I am just mentioning this because I am unsure whether this is unwanted behavior or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out [through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20284303/6509751) I also have to change the `package` attribute for the `<manifest` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and I additionally needed to change the `package` in `MainActivity.java` itself.

I wonder how it could even work when not using `url_launcher`. My guess is that working settings were still apparent in the `build` folder, i.e. in the already built `.class` and `.dex` files.